# How to get current case number when button is clicked lightning component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I have a standard component case page, when i choose one of the case and click on it, it displays 'Case Detail' page. 
Once the 'Case Detail' page is loaded, i have written one lightning component, on click of that lightning component button, i need to get the logged in user information and current case number.

```
<aura:component controller="testController" implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId" access="global" > 

<!-- to get email address -->
<aura:attribute name="Email" type="String"/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.getEmailAddress}"/>

<!- to get the case details -->
<aura:attribute name="casesList" type="case[]" />    
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.getCasesList}"/>
<aura:iteration items="{!v.casesList}" var="case" end="5">
    {!case.CaseNumber}<br/>
</aura:iteration>
</aura:component>
```

The above is displaying all case details. 
User can have multiple case numbers.
But i need only current caseNumber from caseDetail page. 
On button click of my lighning component, i need pass userinfo,casenumber as parameters.

Controller :

```
({ 
getEmailAddress: function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.getUserEmailAddress"); // method in the apex class
    action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
        if (a.getState() === "SUCCESS") {
            component.set("v.Email", a.getReturnValue()); // variable in the component
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},

getCasesList : function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.getCasesListVal");
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        if (response.getState() === "SUCCESS") {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
            component.set("v.casesList" , response.getReturnValue());
        } 
    });    
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
})
```

Below is the apex classs

```
@AuraEnabled
public static String getUserEmailAddress() {
    return UserInfo.getUserEmail();
}

@AuraEnabled
public static List<Case> getCasesListVal()
{
List<Case> casesList = [select id, CaseNumber, Subject, CreatedDate, Status, Priority
                               from Case
                               order by CreatedDate desc
                               limit 5];
    return casesList;        
}
```

Comment: Use the recordId and the lightning data service

Comment: @Eric, the Lighting Data Service is in beta and I wouldn't recommend using it if you build a small component that needs to be deployed to prod.

Comment: Or whatever option you choose. the important part is the recordId attribute

Comment: @Eric, is recordId and caseNumber are same?